# Pass variable to tables2?

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

In trying to follow the DRY principle for python, I am attempting to define some information about a column in tables2 with a variable. I can see that the variable is being passed to my **init** function, but I can't see it in the main body of my class. Is there a better way to do this? Below is a simplified version of the table that I am trying to use.

```
class StuffTable(tables.Table):
  input(self.FontClass) # the variable is not showing up here
  columnAttributes = {"style": "font-size: 12px; max-width:120px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;"}
  columnHeaderAttributes = {"class": f"mb3 { self.FontClass }"}
  columnFooterAttributes = {"style": "font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; max-width:120px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;"}
  Type = tables.Column(verbose_name="", attrs={"th": columnHeaderAttributes, "td": columnAttributes})
  TypeDescription = tables.Column(verbose_name="Type", attrs={"th": columnHeaderAttributes, "td": columnAttributes})
  Column3= tables.Column(attrs={"th": columnHeaderAttributes, "td": columnAttributes})
  Column4= tables.Column(attrs={"th": columnHeaderAttributes, "td": columnAttributes})

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      temp_fontclass = kwargs.pop("FontClass")
      super(StuffTable, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      self.FontClass = temp_fontclass
      input(self.FontClass) # this does show that the variable is being passed
```

Comment: whatever you have between `class` and `def __init__` is not a part of the instance, so it does not have a `self`. You need to put all of this in `__init__`.

Comment: How do I put all of that in the __init__? When I do, the table returns empty.

Answer (score 0):

It won't show up here:

```
class StuffTable(tables.Table):
  input(self.FontClass) # the variable is not showing up here
  columnAttributes = {"style": "font-size: 12px; max-width:120px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;"}
  ...
```

The body of a `class` is defining class variables which get copied as instance variables by `__init__`. A tables2 instance ought to have a `self.FontClass` **after** instantiation, courtesy of your init. Try it in the shell.

```
>>> foo = StuffTable( FontClass='bar', whatever_keeps_it_happy)
>>> foo.FontClass
```

should show "bar". You might define a default `FontClass = 'default'` in your class body, and use `kwargs.pop('FontClass', None)` to make it optional at instantiation time.